# How to get the name of the class that belongs_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming

```
class Foo
  belongs_to :bar
```

What is a good way find out which class is the `belongs_to` relationship?

In this case, it is `Bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a built-in method for this, but as a workaround you can look at `Foo`'s attributes, exploiting the convention that one of them is `bar_id`:

```
Foo.attribute_names.grep(/.*_id/).map{ |bar| bar[0..-4].classify.safe_constantize }
```

**Update**

The built-in method is

```
Foo.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 5):

just try
    Foo.reflect_on_association(:bar).klass

Comment: In case you want the source for this answer: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/klass

Comment: How do you know to use `:bar`? That's point of the question. How to get `:bar`.

Comment: Now that you know where to start is easier to expand the answer to what you actually want: `Foo.reflect_on_all_associations.find_all { |a| a.is_a? ActiveRecord::Reflection::BelongsToReflection }.map(&:name)`